# Operating System: Redundancy of implement a monitor using semaphores in my textbook?

Tags: operating-systems

Why the part highlighted the following picture is need? I've been trying to follow to logic flow of it as follow:

## Imaging a Situation:

Two processes enter/call F, first A, second B:

Process A: `mutex`(value: 1 -> 0) enter the *body of F*, then calls `x.wait()`, so `mutex`(value: 0 -> 1) but this process into waiting state because `x_sem`(value: 0 -> -1) and now `count`(value: 0 -> 1).
Process B: `mutex`(value: 1 -> 0) also enter the *body of F*, then calls `x.signal()`, so since `count > 0` pass, `next_count`(value: 0 -> 1). Now, only at this moment `next_count > 0` will pass, but Process B still holding the mutex.

---

So why the part I highlighted is needed?

The book I'm reading is "Operating System Concepts, 9th ed., pages 229~230."

[image: moni_sema1]
[image: moni_sema2]